# How to display current date in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i am new in laravel . need help how to display current date in laravel 5.1 ..?
this is my form page:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 padding-5px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {!! Form::label('dato','date here', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
            {!! Form::text('dato',Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('d.m.Y'),array('class'=>'form-control datepicker','data-date-format'=>'dd.mm.yyyy','readonly'=>'true')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code,
remove class `datepicker` from, input tag and initialize datepacker like bellow. this will may help you.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 padding-5px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
            <label class="control-label">Date Hear</label>
            <input type="text" name="dato" id="dato" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y'); ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dato").datepicker({
            format: "dd-M-yyyy"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Hirendrasinh S. Rathod,

Comment: i am  applying your code but not display current date[today date] . but date picker is working

Comment: try to remove, class datepicker, will you found value in text field. ?

Comment: yes Hirendrasinh S. Rathod i have removed datepicker after test it but same problem

Comment: review edits, and show us what code you wrote to init date picker ?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6 padding-5px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
            <label for="dato" class="control-label">Date Hear</label>
            <input type="text" name="dato" id="dato"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo date("d.m.Y");?>">
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6 padding-5px"> 
 <div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-xs-12"> 
   <label for="dato" class="control-label"><?php echo date("d.m.Y");?></label>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>

Comment: Hi Hirendrasinh S. Rathod this is display current date. but i need textbox inside and also date picker if want change another date ..

Comment: which datepicker you use ? bootstrap or jquery  ?

Comment: bootstrap date picker Hirendrasinh S. Rathod